# Microsoft SQL Server 2012 column level permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I try to give column level insert (or) update permissions in SQL Server, I get an error.

Query:

```
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE ON [db].[dbo].[table]([column]) TO [user]
```

Error:

> Msg 1020, Level 15, State 1, Line 0
> Sub-entity lists (such as column or security expressions) cannot be specified for entity-level permissions.

Is there any other way, I can give column-level select/update access to the user.

Comment: You can't grant specific `INSERT` permission on a column as that makes no sense; when a row is inserted all columns are as well. Perhaps you meant `SELECT, UPDATE`, as your description seems to suggest.

Comment: Sure, I will try select, update instead.

Comment: Select, update instead of insert, update worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this article [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/grant-object-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), only you can grant SELECT, REFERENCES, and UPDATE permissions on a column.